# c# Deserialize XML into uniquely keyed collection where the key comes from the XML "Id" attribute

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization

The code below currently works and loads XML into a class structure. This structure consists of a collection of items (items), each that have static properties and a collection that I use for a variable number of properties.

Two things I want to do:
1) I want to change the list into something that has a unique key. I tried a dictionary and that didn't work, maybe a HashSet...leading on to...
2) The key for the collection should be driven by the item's "id" XML attribute.

I can't quite figure it out, and trying to copy the KVP pattern I used for an items variable parameters does not work. It adds the items to "items" but they are all empty and the hash for the collection is not populated.

Help please

```
[XmlRoot("ItemsContainer")]
public class Items
{
    [XmlAttribute("Version")]
    public string Version { get; set; }

    [XmlArray("Items")]
    [XmlArrayItem("Item")]
    public List<Item> items = new List<Item>(); //TODO - The key in this collection should be unique and driven from an item's "Id" XML attribute

    public static Items Load(string path)
    {
        var xml = Resources.Load<TextAsset>(path);
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof (Items));
        var reader = new StringReader(xml.text);
        var items = (Items) serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        reader.Close();
        return items;
    }
}


public class Item
{
    //### Fixed Item Parameters
    [XmlAttribute("Id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Value")]
    public float Value { get; set; }

    //### Variable Item Parameters as Key Value pairs.
    [XmlArray("KVPS")]
    [XmlArrayItem("KVP")]
    public List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> KVPS { get; set; } //We will have cases were we don't want unique keys
}

[Serializable]
public class KVP<K, V>
{
    public K Key { get; set; }
    public V Value { get; set; }

    public KVP()
    {
    }

    public KVP(K key, V value)
    {
        Key = key;
        Value = value;
    }
}
```

Here is the associated XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ItemsContainer Version="1.0">
  <Items>

    <Item Id="100">
      <Name>Burger</Name>
      <Description>The lovely tasting Big Mac</Description>
      <Value>5.67</Value>
    </Item>

    <Item Id="101">
      <Name>Sammich</Name>
      <Description>Ham and cheese</Description>
      <Value>2.80</Value>
    </Item>

    <Item Id="102">
      <Name>Carling</Name>
      <Description>Pint of carling</Description>
      <Value>2.80</Value>
      <KVPS>
        <KVP>
          <Key>alchohol</Key>
          <Value>3.9</Value>
        </KVP>
        <KVP>
          <Key>alchohol</Key>
          <Value>4.9</Value>
        </KVP>
        <KVP>
          <Key>alchohol</Key>
          <Value>5.9</Value>
        </KVP>
      </KVPS>
    </Item>

  </Items>
</ItemsContainer>
```

Comment: So you want Id to drive the unique key created? What if Id is duplicated, how should the key be created uniquely? Conversely if Id is not duplicated, it is unique, so why not use Id?

Comment: >So you want Id to drive the unique key created? Yes this was mentioned in my OP. >What if Id is duplicated. As I mentioned it's to go into a Dictionary, so the same handling. >how should the key be created uniquely?  The key has already been created in the XML so it's not a concern here >Conversely if Id is not duplicated, it is unique, so why not use Id? Thats what I'm asking for in my OP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this.  I changed StringReader to StreamReader just for my testing.  You can change it back

```
public static Dictionary<int, Item> Load(string path)
        {
            //var xml = Resources.Load<TextAsset>(path);
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Items));
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path);
            Items items = (Items)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
            reader.Close();
            Dictionary<int, Item> dict = items.items.GroupBy(x => x.Id).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());
            return dict;
        }
```

Comment: This was the type of method I went with in the end which strictly speaking I see as an alternative rather than a solution. The reason I say that is because an extra step is added to copy the List into a Dictionary rather than just use the Dictionary directly from the get go. One way to do this in one step is to manually walk the XML using XDocument or use IXmlSerializable and do something similar. However I think for this scope, this should be considered the solution.

Comment: You can use items.items.GroupBy(x => x.Id).ToList() to get each item.  Then enumerate through the list adding each to existing dictionary.   Add(x.Key, x)